# Selenium .text() doesn't get all text from webpage, and also doesn't omit strikeout text (<strike class>)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, text

Hi i'm having issues with selenium

My first issue is that when scraping, I accidentally obtain all "strike class" (striked-out) text from the below link, and I want to avoid that text.

My second issue is that selenium won't capture all the text from my webpage --Selenium gets about half of the text from the below link and stops in the middle of the sentence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
driver.get("https://custom.statenet.com/public/resources.cgi?id=ID:bill:KY2022000H740&ciq=ncsl32&client_md=4cf283759f8caf88663f3af9e2707c25&mode=current_text")
    
all_elems = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
        
all_text = all_elems.text
        
strikedout_elems = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'strike')
        
strikedout_text = strikedout_elems.text

wanted_text = all_text.replace(undesired_text, "")
        
wanted_text = wanted_text.replace("\n\n", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the overheads of Selenium to obtain the text from that page, it can be acomplished with Requests and BeautifulSoup, like below (also ignoring the strikeout texts):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://custom.statenet.com/public/resources.cgi?id=ID:bill:KY2022000H740&ciq=ncsl32&client_md=4cf283759f8caf88663f3af9e2707c25&mode=current_text')
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
bad_texts = soup.select('strike[class="amendmentDeletedText"]')
for b in bad_texts:
    b.decompose()
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
print(text)
```

This will return you all the text in that (static) page, and also remove the extra whitespace. Of course, there are more elegant ways of getting that text, like isolating paragraphs and subtitles, etc. However, this should respond your question.

Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Whoops so sorry for the last comment -- your approach DID work (had some confusion on my part), however is there  a way to retain the paragraph structure? Thank you very much!

Comment: I test my code before posting: the solution above will remove all elements with `strike[class="amendmentDeletedText"]` selector, which is all strikeout text. It responded your question as asked. If you want to preserve the structure, just remove `strip=True` from `get_text()`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the text book-ending strikeouts lose their spaces in between (e.g., "The dog ~~ran~~ fast" --> "The dogfast"). Is there a way to fix this as well?

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip. I've gave you the solution checkmark :) if you could just help with the losing spaces in between text I mentioned in the above comment, that'd be great, but you've already gone above and beyond! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome @ZZTop. In case you still have the issue of losing spaces between words after removing `strip=True`, you can try replacing the `decompose()` method with simply replacing the unwanted paragraphs with a single space, using a `for` loop.